# Creating hidden section in Flask, WTForms

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms, wtforms

I have a form using Flask and WTForms, the form has few required fields but a long list of optional fields. My problem is that I don’t want the page to be really long when the majority of users will only use the default, what I'm trying to do is have a 'section' that they can click on and it would expand with the optional questions. My code currently looks like:

```
class form_contact(FlaskForm):
Name = StringField('Name:', validators=[DataRequired()])
Number = StringField('Phone Number:', validators=[DataRequired()])
Address = StringField('Address:', validators=[DataRequired()])
 
OptionA = StringField('Optional Field 1:', validators=[])
OptionB = StringField('Optional Field 2:', validators=[])
OptionC = StringField('Optional Field 3:', validators=[])
OptionD = StringField('Optional Field 4:', validators=[])
 
@app.route('/', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
form = form_contact()
 
# form processing is here
 
return render_template('index.html', form=form0
 
if __name__ == '__main__':
app.run()
```

I tried using the hiddefield field but that didn’t accomplish what I’m trying to do

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like:

```
@app.route('/', methods = ['GET', 'POST'], defaults={'showmore': False})
@app.route('/<showmore>', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    form = form_contact()
    return render_template('index.html', form=form0, showmore=showmore)
```

and in your `index.html` template add to where you want the form to show up when you click the button: `{% if showmore %} add expanded form section {% endif %}`.

You will also want to make your expansion button equal to `/True/`.

It isn't perfect - but it should achieve what you want it to. You can also likely build the entire form, set CSS property to hide the expanded area, and then use jQuery or Javascript to show the form on-click. But if you want to stick to pure Python the above should work.